# How to access other class's object in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qmainwindow

In the program, I want to click a button in the main window and trigger the sub-window to display the image. But I cannot access ui->graphsView in the main window.cpp, how can I do that? In the main.cpp. the click-button function is assumed to do such thing. The QGraphicsView is placed in the ShowPic class.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include "showpic.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel *model;
    ShowPic *showpic;
    QString filesPath;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

showpic.h

```
#ifndef SHOWPIC_H
#define SHOWPIC_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ShowPic;
}

class ShowPic : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ShowPic(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ShowPic();

private:
    Ui::ShowPic *ui;
};

#endif // SHOWPIC_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QFileDialog>
#include<QFileSystemModel>
#include<QStringList>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    showpic = new ShowPic();
    showpic->show();
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QPixmap pixmap("C:\test\\image.jpg");
    scene.addPixmap(pixmap);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene); ///????
}
```

showpic.cpp

```
#include "showpic.h"
#include "ui_showpic.h"

ShowPic::ShowPic(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ShowPic)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ShowPic::~ShowPic()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: where have you created graphsView?

Comment: I dragged the graphsView to the ShowPic window.

Comment: it is not necessary to access graphsView from MainWindow, a simple solution is to pass the pixmap to ShowPic, create a method that receives the pixmap and add it to the graphsView in ShowPic.

Comment: Thanks. Could you demonstrate how to do that?

Comment: Try with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you have to add the QGraphicsScene only once, and a suitable place is in the constructor:

```
ShowPic::ShowPic(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ShowPic)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
}
```

Then we create a method that receives the pixmap and adds it to the scene:

**showpic.h**

```
[...]
explicit ShowPic(QWidget *parent = 0);
~ShowPic();
void addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap);
[...]
```

**showpic.h**

```
[...]
void ShowPic::addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap){
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
}
[...]
```

And we use that method in the slot on_pushButton_clicked:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    showpic = new ShowPic();
    QPixmap pixmap("C:\test\\image.jpg");
    showpic->addPixmap(pixmap);
    showpic->show();
}
```